# MVC Model to View event dispatch implementation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javabeans

The MVC pattern wants that Model dispatches change status events to View.
Which is the best implementation of this comunication if the Model is a simple javabean with setter and getter methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bean, allow the registration of [PropertyChangeListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)s, it's the designated observer class for change notification on java beans.

Example bean with PropertyChangeListener support:

```
public class TestBean {

    private transient final List<PropertyChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener>();

    private String name;

    public void addPropertyChangeListener (PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener (PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private void firePropertyChange (String property, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {

        if (oldValue == newValue || oldValue != null && oldValue.equals(newValue)) {
            return;
        }

        PropertyChangeEvent evt = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, property, oldValue, newValue);
        for (PropertyChangeListener listener : new ArrayList<PropertyChangeListener>(listeners)) {
            listener.propertyChange(evt);
        }
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name) {

        firePropertyChange("name", this.name, this.name = name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it tells me not only how to dispatch the event, but also how to report to listeners witch attribute has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for the communication between the Model and the View. The Model should be the [Observable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and the View should be the [Observer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html).